# How do I have to change this XML string so that XDocument.Parse reads it in?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml

In the following code, I **serialize** an object into an XML **string**.

But when I try to read this XML string **into an XDocument** with XDocument.Parse, it gives me this **error**:

> Invalid data at root level.

The XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Id>1</Id>
   <FirstName>Jim</FirstName>
   <LastName>Jones</LastName>
   <ZipCode>23434</ZipCode>
</Customer>
```

**UPDATE:** Here is the hex:

`![alt text][1]` *Mod edit - disabled hyperlink: links to malware*

**What do I have to do to this XML so that it reads into the XDocument without an error?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace TestSerialize2342
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Customer> customers = Customer.GetCustomers();

            Console.WriteLine("--- Serializing ------------------");

            foreach (var customer in customers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Serializing " + customer.GetFullName() + "...");
                string xml = XmlHelpers.SerializeObject<Customer>(customer);

                XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    public static class StringHelpers
    {
        public static String UTF8ByteArrayToString(Byte[] characters)
        {
            UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            String constructedString = encoding.GetString(characters);
            return (constructedString);
        }

        public static Byte[] StringToUTF8ByteArray(String pXmlString)
        {
            UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(pXmlString);
            return byteArray;
        } 
    }

    public static class XmlHelpers
    {
        public static string SerializeObject<T>(object o)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
            xs.Serialize(xtw, o);
            ms = (MemoryStream)xtw.BaseStream;
            return StringHelpers.UTF8ByteArrayToString(ms.ToArray());
        }

        public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string xml)
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(StringHelpers.StringToUTF8ByteArray(xml));
            XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
            return (T)xs.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        private int internalValue = 23;

        public static List<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
            customers.Add(new Customer { Id = 1, FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Jones", ZipCode = "23434" });
            customers.Add(new Customer { Id = 2, FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Adams", ZipCode = "12312" });
            customers.Add(new Customer { Id = 3, FirstName = "Jack", LastName = "Johnson", ZipCode = "23111" });
            customers.Add(new Customer { Id = 4, FirstName = "Angie", LastName = "Reckar", ZipCode = "54343" });
            customers.Add(new Customer { Id = 5, FirstName = "Henry", LastName = "Anderson", ZipCode = "16623" });
            return customers;
        }

        public string GetFullName()
        {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName + "(" + internalValue + ")";
        }

    }
}
```

## ANSWER:

Thanks Andras, GetPreamble() fixed it, so for anyone else dealing with this, here is a little method to clean your XML of the BOM:

```
public static string RemoveUtf8ByteOrderMark(string xml)
{
    string byteOrderMarkUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
    if (xml.StartsWith(byteOrderMarkUtf8))
    {
        xml = xml.Remove(0, byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length);
    }
    return xml;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that XML. Are you sure it's the same XML that's causing the exception?

Comment: Invalid data at root level, line 1, character 1. When I copy the text into NotePad++, the first character is a "?" and in other editors some control character...

Comment: Then you lost the open "<" during the cut and paste. There's nothing wrong with the XML.

Comment: it's byte order marks or similar - but I don't recognise that one!

Comment: I think I have a more elegant solution, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's because the data contains the unicode or utf8 [BOM marks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getpreamble(VS.80).aspx) at the start of the stream.

You need to skip past any Byte Order Marks in the stream - you can identify these from the [System.Text.Encoding.GetPreamble()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getpreamble(VS.80).aspx) method.

Comment: you frequently get this problem when creating XML files in Notepad.  VS can also add them sometimes too.

Comment: Using GetPreamble() is an attempt to solve consequences instead of reason. Look at my answer please.

Comment: Yes that's a good answer - and it works, if the encoding is always UTF8.

However, by using the GetPreamble method you can auto-detect the encoding of a file, meaning that you're not tied to just one. Once selected you could then adjust your code sample to accomodate any encoding.

Comment: Agree, but why you should have more complex solution foreseeing future encodings that could never be needed. I wouldn't suggest this if you only need  UTF8 at the moment. YAGNI.

Comment: It really isn't that difficult or that complicated, I have an extension method in a common reference library that I use,  and which is probably about 10-15 lines of code.  I know what you're saying,  and I agree in principle,  but sometimes the complete solution is worth it,  especially if it doesn't raise complexity any great amount.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve your problem by using a `StreamReader` to convert the data in the `MemoryStream` to a string instead:

```
public static string SerializeObject<T>(object o)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (XmlWriter xtw = XmlWriter.Create(ms))
        {
            xs.Serialize(xtw, o);
            xtw.Flush();
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: `XmlTextWriter` is deprecated. Use `XmlWriter.Create` instead.

Comment: @John: the compiler issues no information about `XmlTextWriter` being deprecated. I know about the `XmlWriter.Create` recommendation, but I did not want to alter the OP code more than necessary to solve the issue. Still, updated my code sample to follow the recommendation.

Answer (score -1):

All above is correct, and here is a code that you should use instead of yours to skip BOM:

```
 public static string SerializeObject<T>(object o)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            //here is my code
            UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
            XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(ms, encoding);
            //XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
            xs.Serialize(xtw, o);
            ms = (MemoryStream)xtw.BaseStream;
            return StringHelpers.UTF8ByteArrayToString(ms.ToArray());
       }
```

By specifying *false* in the constructor you say "BOM is not provided". Enjoy! =)

Comment: -1,-1,-1: You need to put `using` blocks around the `MemoryStream` and the `XmlWriter`. You need to not use `XmlTextWriter`, which has been deprecated since .NET 2.0 - use `XmlWriter.Create` instead. The `o` parameter should be of type `T`; among other things, this would allow your callers to not specify <T> - it will often be implied by the type of the parameter.

Comment: Agree, but this is a COPY of the ORIGINAL code with only one modification, so it wasn't my target to review it and find holes and design issues. If you will try to read this discussion, you probably will notice that I've solved the problem I WAS ASKED FOR. So take your "-1" out, sir.